# Inicialização de dados de uma classe

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor

Existe alguma função de inicialização de classes para C++?

Em Lua, usando a biblioteca `classlib` há a função `__init`, e em Python também.
EX:

```
require "classlib"

Human = class();

function Human:__init(name, age)
  self.name = name
  self.age = age
end

gabriel = Human("Gabriel", 16)

print(gabriel.name, gabriel.age)
```

Em C++ tive que fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class human {
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        void SET(string, int);
};

    void human::SET(string name, int age){
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
int main (){
    human gabriel;
    gabriel.SET("Gabriel Sales", 16);
    cout << gabriel.name;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer fazer, você chegou perto. O que falta você conhecer é o [construtor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) da classe.

Ele é um método especial que é executado antes da instância desta classe estar disponível, ou seja, é este método que constrói a instância. O seu uso não é mera formalidade. Ele dá algumas garantias que não vou detalhar agora já que você está começando.

Note que o construtor tem o mesmo nome da classe e não tem um tipo de retorno, nem mesmo `void`.

Note também que o inicializador tem uma sintaxe esquisita. Parece que a variável é uma função. De uma certa forma isto poderia ser visto como se fosse `human gabriel = human("Gabriel Sales", 16);`. E esta sintaxe também funciona. Tente com ela também. Ele não é tão usada porque fica muito longa e redundante.

Tem outras maneiras de inicializar especialmente no C++11 que é a versão mais recente mas esse é a mais utilizada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class human {
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        human(string, int);
};

human::human(string name, int age) {
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
}

int main() {
    human gabriel("Gabriel Sales", 16);
    cout << gabriel.name;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KjV6FV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kpdbcpen-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/InitClass.cpp).

Comment: Exatamente isto.

Comment: @bigown Só em C++ o `this` é um ponteiro e tem que ser tratado assim -> ?

Comment: @axell13 não, se tiver alguma dúvida específica, quiser comparação com alguma linguagem, faça uma pergunta que eu tento responder.