# Formas de instanciar um objeto e declarar construtores

Tags: c++, construtor, instanciar-objeto

Em C++ existem diversas maneiras de se criar um construtor e de instanciar um objeto. Porém são tantas maneiras que estou confuso com a diferença de cada uma.

Supondo que eu tenha a seguinte classe:

```
using namespace std;
class Carro
{
    private:
        string modelo;
        string marca;
    public:
        Carro(){}
        Carro(string x, string y) { modelo = x; marca = y;}
}
```

Qual seria a diferença entre as seguintes formas de se instanciar o objeto?

```
Carro carro = new Carro;

Carro carro;

Carro carro();

Carro carro("Astra", "Chevrolet");

Carro *carro = new Carro;    // Usando ponteiro

Carro *carro = new Carro();  // Usando ponteiro
```

Gostaria também de saber como funciona o `:` na hora de declarar um construtor, por exemplo:

```
Carro(string x, string y) : modelo(x), marca(y) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Carro carro = new Carro;
```

Não é possível.

```
Carro carro;
```

Está declarando a variável do tipo `Carro` mas nada está sendo atribuído para esta variável. Ela é armazenada no próprio *stack*.

```
Carro carro();
```

Está declarando uma função que retorna um tipo `Carro`. Não faz muito sentido neste contexto.

```
Carro carro("Astra", "Chevrolet");
```

Está chamando um construtor da classe que recebe os parâmetros especificados.

```
Carro *carro = new Carro;
```

Muda a forma de inicialização. Na maior parte dos casos não faz diferença. Existem casos que a inicialização poderá ocorrer por padrão ou por valor. Neste exemplo o resultado será o mesmo mas dependendo de como a classe seja declarada, pode inicializar de forma diferente. Não sei de todos os detalhes sobre isto.

```
Carro *carro = new Carro();
```

Está alocando no *heap*, por isto precisa criar uma **nova** alocação de memória e o endereço desta alocação será atribuído obviamente para um ponteiro e não diretamente o tipo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Initialization.cpp).

[Entenda sobre *stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

[Saiba mais sobre construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

[Veja sobre sobrecarga e assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

[Informações sobre alocação e ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101).

[Mais informações porque usar ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101).

[Como decidir se deve usar ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101).

[Pergunta semelhante com mais alguns detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44627/101).

A última questão já é outro assunto e deveria ser outra pergunta mas acho que pode entender em [pergunta já feita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79864/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No caso da terceira, `Carro carro()`, quando eu chamo algum método, ao compilar eu recebo o seguinte erro: `error: request for member 'getModelo' in 'carro', which is of non-class type 'Carro()`. Isso teria algo a ver com o stack?

Comment: Poderia mas não tem como eu saber já que este método não existe na classe que você mostrou. Mas como o erro é outro eu imagino que adicionou ele depois. Então sim, tem situações que a classe no *stack* pode não funcionar como esperada.

Comment: Encontrei o motivo deste erro. Na verdade, o que acontece nesse caso é que o compilador interpreta `carro()` como um outro tipo de construtor, e não como o construtor padrão (o construtor padrão começa com maiúscula). O compilador irá interpretar como construtor padrão apenas se os parênteses estiverem omitidos, que é o caso da segunda opção (`Carro carro;`). Encontrei a solução aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type

Comment: Sim, tem isto também, mas você estava falando de coisas que sequer estão presentas no que você postou. Não é o caso da primeira porque ela está tentando alocar no *heap*, não havendo está confusão. Mas a primeira está errada porque está tentando jogar um ponteiro como valor da classe.

Answer (score 4):

Ficaram algumas pequenas nuances por explicar, por isso deixo aqui alguns comentários.

Para o teu exemplo

```
using namespace std;
class Carro
{
    private:
        string modelo;
        string marca;
    public:
        Carro(){}
        Carro(string x, string y) { modelo = x; marca = y;}
}
```

- **Carro carro = new Carro;**

  - Esta instrução é inválida/a sintaxe não é válida no C++
- **Carro carro;**

  - Declara uma variável do tipo Carro no escopo (scope) local, geralmente na stack, que será automaticamente destruida quando o escopo (scope) terminar.
- **Carro carro();**

  - Declara não uma variável mas **sim uma função** sem argumentos, que devolve um objecto do tipo Carro. Esta é a razão pela qual obtens a seguinte mensagem de erro: `error: request for member 'getModelo' in 'carro', which is of non-class type 'Carro().` Fica fácil agora perceber o porquê do erro.
- **Carro carro("Astra", "Chevrolet");**

  - Declara uma variável do tipo Carro no escopo (scope) local, geralmente na stack, que será automaticamente destruida quando o escopo (scope) terminar. Ao contrário do segundo exemplo, aqui não será executado o construtor default, mas sim o construtor que recebe dois argumentos.
- **Carro *carro = new Carro;**    // Usando ponteiro

  - Chamada ao construtor por defeito (inicialização por defeito)
- **Carro *carro = new Carro();**  // Usando ponteiro

  - Chamada ao construtor por defeito (inicialização por valor)

Nos dois últimos exemplos a diferença prende-se com a inicialização dos membros da classe, mas para o teu exemplo em particular, não existe diferença prática. As instruções alocam um espaço de memória através da chamada ao operador `new()` e implicitamente efectuam uma chamada ao constructor C`arro::Carro()`, com o apontador `this` a apontar para um espaço nessa memória (devolvido pelo `new(`)). Este endereço é depois guardado no apontador `carro` (stack). Uma vez que a memória alocado não é libertada automaticamente quando o escopo termina, é necessário efectuar a gestão de memória de forma manual através da instrução `delete`.

Se quiseres ler mais em relação à diferença entre

```
Carro *carro = new Carro;    // Usando ponteiro
Carro *carro = new Carro();  // Usando ponteiro
```

Podes ler o próprio standard da linguagem:

> To ***zero-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>   — if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> To ***default-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> To ***value-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized
>
> A program that calls for default-initialization or value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed. If T is a cv-qualified type, the cv-unqualified version of T is used for these definitions of zero-initialization, default-initialization, and value-initialization.

Esta é mais uma das preciosidades do C++ que todos nós adoramos. :)