# Como criar uma quantidade de objetos definida pelo usuário?

Tags: c++

Estou criando um bookshop e na hora de registrar um novo livro, o usuário deve dizer a quantidade de livros que serão registrados, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso, apenas consigo criar uma quantidade de objeto pré-definida.

Aqui no código tentei criar uma array, porém ela exige que seja uma constante impedido que o usuário de definir a quantidade que será criada.

```
void AddNewBook() {
    system("CLS");

    int amountBooks;

    std::cout << "How many books will be added? ";
    std::cin >> amountBooks;

    if (amountBooks < 1) {
         Error("No book will be added.");
         Options(Choice());
    }
    else {
        Book books[amountBooks];
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de criar a quantidade de objetos que o usuário precisa dinamicamente?

Peço perdão caso não esteja claro minha duvida.

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678457/dynamic-objects-in-c/44678941#:~:text=If%20you%20write%20A%20*%20a,A%20and%20not%20an%20array. e esse também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87980/formas-de-instanciar-um-objeto-e-declarar-construtores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível criar array alocado estaticamente usando um tamanho não constante (que não seja conhecido na hora da compilação).

Meios corretos de se declarar um array:

```
char array[5];

const size_t amount = 10;
char array[amount];

#define amount 15;
char array[amount];

static constexpr size_t amount = 20;
char array[amount];
```

Para criar um array que tenha tamanho dinâmico, basta usar um dos templates da biblioteca std, o `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Book> books;
Book book;
books.push_back(book);
```

Usa-se `push_back()` para adicionar elementos ao vetor e operador `[]` para acessá-los assim como em um array. Não é necessário especificar um tamanho na hora da inicialização, mas para diminuir a quantidade de alocações (e aumentar a performance), você pode usar `reserve()` para predefinir o tamanho do `vector`.