# É possível criar um objeto automaticamente em c++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, método

É possível criar um objeto automaticamente? Eu tenho uma classe Funcionário com seus respectivos métodos, conforme o código abaixo. Como faço para instanciar cada novo objeto automaticamente? Exemplo: funcionario3, funcionario4,...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Funcionario{
    public:
        Funcionario(){}

        // função que define o nome do funcionário
        void setNome(string nome){
            nomeFuncionario = nome;
        }

        // função que define o cpf
        void setCPF(string CPF){
            cpf = CPF;
        }

        // função que define a data de admissão
        void setDataAdmissao(string data_admissao){
            data = data_admissao;
        }

        // função que define o salário
        void setSalarioFuncionario(float salario_funcionario){
            salario = salario_funcionario;
        }

        // função que obtém o nome do funcionário
        string getNome(){
            return nomeFuncionario;
        }

        // função que obtém o cpf
        string getCPF(){
            return cpf;
        }

        // função que obtém a data de admissão
        string getDataAdmissao(){
            return data;
        }

        // função que obtém o salário
        float getSalarioFuncionario(){
            return salario;
        }


    private:
        string nomeFuncionario, cpf, data;
        float salario;
};

int main(){

    string nomeDoFuncionario, dataAdmissao, cpf;
    float salario;

// Funcionario 1

    Funcionario funcionario1; // cria o objeto RepresentacaoFuncionario chamado Funcionario1

    // Chamadas das funções para definir os dados do funcionario
    cout << "Entre com o nome do funcionário:" << endl;
    getline(cin, nomeDoFuncionario);
    funcionario1.setNome(nomeDoFuncionario);

    cout << "Entre com a data de admissão:" << endl;
    cin >> dataAdmissao;
    funcionario1.setDataAdmissao(dataAdmissao);

    cout << "Entre com o cpf do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> cpf;
    funcionario1.setCPF(cpf);

    cout << "Entre com o salário do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> salario;
    funcionario1.setSalarioFuncionario(salario);

// Funcionario 2

Funcionario funcionario2; // cria o objeto RepresentacaoFuncionario chamado Funcionario2

    // Chamadas das funções para definir os dados do funcionario
    cout << "Entre com o nome do funcionário:" << endl;
    getline(cin, nomeDoFuncionario);
    funcionario2.setNome(nomeDoFuncionario);

    cout << "Entre com a data de admissão:" << endl;
    cin >> dataAdmissao;
    funcionario2.setDataAdmissao(dataAdmissao);

    cout << "Entre com o cpf do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> cpf;
    funcionario2.setCPF(cpf);

    cout << "Entre com o salário do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> salario;
    funcionario2.setSalarioFuncionario(salario);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Formas de instanciar um objeto e declarar construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87980/formas-de-instanciar-um-objeto-e-declarar-construtores)

Comment: Como seria essa automação? fiquei curioso. Você pode criar construtores, que como esperado: constroem instâncias da classe. É o  óbvio. Mas o que quer fazer?

Comment: @arfneto eu vi uma solução mas não sei se é válida, foi criado um vetor do tipo objeto, e cada objeto criado era adicionado nesse vetor. 
A minha intensão seria criar um objeto novo a cada registro de funcionário, como se fosse de forma recursiva

Answer (score 1):

Você escreveu praticamente um programa `C`. Talvez não tenha ainda ficado clara para você a diferença entre essas linguagens e o que significa uma instância da classe.
Um objeto é sempre criado "automaticamente" em `C++`. Ao criar uma instância da classe como em seu código

```
    Funcionario funcionario1;
```

o compilador vai buscar a partir dos parâmetros um construtor de classe para ser executado, e acho que esse é o *"automático"* de que você fala no título.
Se não tiver nenhum o construtor padrão é gerado e invocado.
no seu caso o construtor foi escrito:

```
    Funcionario() {}
```

Que no popular significa **nada**. A mesma coisa que não ter escrito essa linha.

Imagino que você não pretendia ter que chamar uma função para cada campo de cada instância da classe. Por sorte são 4 e não 40 campos.

Métodos em `C++` são polimórficos e vou te mostrar 2 exemplos de como se costuma fazer isso.

#### Sobre seu código

- não é prático declarar mais uma variável por linha. Só atrapalha.
- evite comentários com acentos. E comentários do tipo

```
    // função que define a data de admissão
    void setDataAdmissao(string data_admissao)
```

a menos que ache que um comentário assim realmente acrescenta algo ao código

- não misture código de entrada e saída com a lógica do programa
- evite nomes muito grandes sem necessidade. Todos os membros de `Funcionario` se referem a `Funcionario` então provavelmente não precisa de `nomeFuncionario` e pode usar apenas `nome`.
- não escreva um programa interativo nunca. Se precisar disso coloque depois de testar o resto
- Use dois arquivos para cada classe. Não misture o código de classe ao código de `main()`. Só vai te atrapalhar nos testes e no uso da classe

#### Exemplo 1

```
Funcionario::Funcionario(string n, string cpf, string d, float salario) :
    nome(n), cpf(cpf), data(d), salario(salario) {}
```

Esse construtor faz o que acabou fazendo em seu código, mas veja a diferença

```
    // Funcionario 1
    cout << "Entre com o nome do funcionário: " << endl;
    getline(cin, nome);
    cout << "Entre com a data de admissão:" << endl; 
    cin >> data;
    cout << "Entre com o cpf do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> cpf;
    cout << "Entre com o salário do funcionário:" << endl;
    cin >> salario;

    Funcionario f1(nome, cpf, data, salario); // primeiro
```

E o programa lê os dados em separado. Depois da leitura declara a instância usando o construtor apropriado. O resultado é exatamente o mesmo de seu código.

#### Exemplo 2

```
        Funcionario::Funcionario() : salario(0.) {};
```

Esse é o construtor padrão, porque não tem parâmetros. A diferença deste construtor para não escrever um construtor ou usar apenas `{}` como você tinha feito é que nesse caso `salario` fica com `0.`. Os outros campos são da classe `string` e ela tem seu construtor padrão e os campos ficam em branco, mas `salario` é `float` e o valor inicial é indefinido.

```
        Funcionario f3;
```

`f3` como não tem parâmetros vai usar o construtor padrão e `salario` vai ficar com `0.`. e os outros campos em branco.

#### Exemplo 3

Imagine uma classe `Setor` que tem um nome e um ponteiro para os `n` funcionários

eis a classe

```c
class Setor
{
public:
    unsigned n;
    string nome;
    Funcionario* f;

    Setor(string nome, unsigned n) : nome(nome), n(n)
    { f = new Funcionario[n]; }

    ~Setor()
    { delete[] f; } // apaga os funcionarios
};
```

Que você pode criar assim

```
        Setor ctn("Contabilidade", 10);
```

Talvez seja isso o que pretendia dizer com *automático*: essa única linha cria um `Setor`, e ao fazer isso cria 30 ponteiros para os `Funcionário`. E o `new` como escrito invoca o construtor padrão, que foi modificado para gerar valores numerados. Assim se pode testar o programa sem ler dados e com qualquer volume de funcionários no setor. Afinal ninguém vai querer ficar digitando 10 deles afinal. Ou 10.000...

Então considere

```
    Setor ctn("Contabilidade", 10);
    cout << "Setor " << ctn.nome << " tem " << ctn.n << "  funcionarios:\n"
        "  Nome\t\tSalario\n";
    for (auto i = 0; i < ctn.n; i += 1)
        cout << ctn.f[i].getNome() <<
            "\t\t" << ctn.f[i].getSalario() << "\n";
    cout << endl;
```

Que mostra

```
Setor Contabilidade tem 10  funcionarios:
  Nome          Salario
Nome 1          1.01
Nome 2          2.02
Nome 3          3.03
Nome 4          4.04
Nome 5          5.05
Nome 6          6.06
Nome 7          7.07
Nome 8          8.08
Nome 9          9.09
Nome 10         10.1
```

**Nota** Não se escreve assim há tempos, com `new` e `delete`. Só estou mostrando como se valer desse lance de polimorfismo e o construtor padrão para ter mais exemplos relacionados à sua pergunta.

Eis o construtor padrão para esse exemplo

```
Funcionario::Funcionario()
{   // gera um funcionario com
    // "Nome n" "CPF n" "Data n" e salario n
    char nm[20];
    static int num = 0;
    num += 1;
    sprintf(nm, "Nome %d", num);
    nome = nm;
    sprintf(nm, "Data %d", num);
    data = nm;
    sprintf(nm, "CPF %3d.123.456-78", num);
    cpf = nm;
    salario = (float)num + num / 100.f;
};
```